# Allow two components to communicate (where one is not inside the other)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning

Is there any way for two components to communicate, where one is not inside the other?

Imagine a community builder page, where you want to insert two separate components (maybe even on different pages). Is there any way to have these components send information to one another?

Like interacting w/ Component A changes Component B (but Component B is not a part of Component A)?

Comment: Yes. You can use application events for that.

Answer (score 2):

As long as they're on the *same* page, you can use [application events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_handling.htm), while if they're on completely different pages, you can theoretically use [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to speak across windows (as long as you're on the same domain), using the "change" event.

You'll want to read [Handling Bubbled or Captured Application Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_handling_phases.htm) for more details. You need an aura:event, which will be registered via aura:registerEvent at the source, and aura:handler at the destination. If communication is two-way, then they'll both need these handlers. It's recommended that you use some sort of identifier in the event to determine who the intended recipient is.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to communicate between two components that are not in the same hierarchy is via [events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm). You can create an event and then fire it from component A. Component B can then handle the event and react appropriately.

I copied some sample code from [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_demo.htm) page, which also contains a thorough explanation of how it works.

**Event Markup**

```
<!--c:appEvent-->
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <!-- pass context of where the event was fired to the handler. -->
    <aura:attribute name="context" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

**Component Raising the Event**

*Markup*

```
<!--c:eventsNotifier-->
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="parentName" type="String"/>
  <aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:appEvent"/>

  <div>
    <h3>This is {!v.parentName}'s eventsNotifier.cmp instance</h3>
    <p><ui:button
        label="Click here to fire an application event"
        press="{!c.fireApplicationEvent}" />
    </p>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

*Controller*

```
/* eventsNotifierController.js */
{

    fireApplicationEvent : function(cmp, event) {
        var parentName = cmp.get("v.parentName");

        // note different syntax for getting application event
        var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:appEvent");

        appEvent.setParams({ "context" : parentName });
        appEvent.fire();
    }
}
```

**Component Handling to the Event**

*Markup*

```
<!--c:eventsHandler-->
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="name" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="mostRecentEvent" type="String" default="Most recent event handled:"/>
  <aura:attribute name="numApplicationEventsHandled" type="Integer" default="0"/>

  <aura:handler event="c:appEvent" action="{!c.handleApplicationEventFired}"/>

  <div>
    <h3>This is {!v.name}</h3>
    <p>{!v.mostRecentEvent}</p>
    <p># application events handled: {!v.numApplicationEventsHandled}</p>
    <c:eventsNotifier parentName="{#v.name}" />
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

*Controller*

```
/* eventsHandlerController.js */
{


    handleApplicationEventFired : function(cmp, event) {
        var context = event.getParam("context");
        cmp.set("v.mostRecentEvent", 
            "Most recent event handled: APPLICATION event, from " + context);

        var numApplicationEventsHandled =
            parseInt(cmp.get("v.numApplicationEventsHandled")) + 1;
        cmp.set("v.numApplicationEventsHandled", numApplicationEventsHandled);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would application events work if these components were one different pages? (For example, if clicking an option on Component A took you to a page with Component B on it, and the information displayed by component B depends on which option you clicked on for Componenet A))?

Comment: Well, it *could*, depend on your architecture. If you're going to a page thats already open, probably not. If you're opening a page yourself via "navigate", then you may not even need events. You could pass parameters to the to-be-created page. 

(Safe Harbor here) I know SFDC is working on a console and, as long as your pages are both in the console, all pages will hear the event.

Comment: I'd like to be able to communicate between apps, or between user operations in the Classic UI, and an app.  One way might be to use Lightning Data Service, and have the app load some kind of session record with force:recordData, and then have that record updated by whatever's doing the operation.  When the record is updated, it might be possible for the listening app to notice that and act on it accordingly.  I haven't played around with LDS yet, but it sounds promising for these types of use cases.